# Newtonsoft.Json causes failure of Visual Studio 2015 Code Analysis

Tags: json.net, visual-studio-2015

Newtonsoft.Json version in NuGet (version 7.0.1) gives the below error message when running code analysis.

```
CA0001 : Could not resolve reference to mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, ...
```

The error occurs in portable class library that targets .Net 4.5, Windows 8 & ASP.NET Core 5.0

The error does not occur if the portable class library targets .Net 4.6, Windows Universal 10 & ASP.NET Core 5.0

I took Newtonsoft.Json source code and compiled to portable class library targeting .Net 4.5, Windows 8 & ASP.NET Core 5.0. Then I referred to the assembly I compiled instead of the NuGet package. The code analysis problem does not happen in this scenario.

Note that I use Visual Studio 2105 running on Windows 10. Targeting .Net 4.6 is not an option for me due to other dependencies.

Please let me know if there is a good way to make the NuGet package work for the particular PCL target I need and code analysis.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem with an older version of Json.NET

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the error by adding a CodeAnalysisAdditionalOptions `/assemblyCompareMode:None` to your .csproj file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  ...
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    ....
    <CodeAnalysisAdditionalOptions>/assemblyCompareMode:None</CodeAnalysisAdditionalOptions>
    ....
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    ....
    <CodeAnalysisAdditionalOptions>/assemblyCompareMode:None</CodeAnalysisAdditionalOptions>
    ....
  </PropertyGroup>
  ....
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the bug was fixed in [Version 9.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases).